# Use C DLL in C# project

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I made a project for my ATM card reader in a C++ project and it works fine. When I try to use the same header file and DLL in a C# project, I keep on getting this error:

```
System.ExecutionEngineException: 'Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown.'
```

**C++ Code**

```cpp
HANDLE port = CommOpenWithBaut(1, 9600);

if (port == 0)
{
    cerr << "Cannot open device";
    return -1;
}

unsigned char PewSt = 0;
unsigned char CardType = 0;
unsigned char CardSt = 0;
unsigned char PowerSt = 0;

int rc = CarderCheckSt(port, PewSt, CardType, CardSt, PowerSt);
//cout << "This is the card Status: " << CarderCheckSt << endl;
int bufferSize = 128;
BYTE buffer[128];

int bytesRead = MagRead(port, buffer, bufferSize);
string text(buffer, buffer + bufferSize);
cerr << "Card Details : " <<text;

CommClose(port);
```

Port is the handle for configuring the port function `CommOpenWithBaut()`. `CarderCheckSt()` checks the status of the ATM card reader. `MagRead()` has the buffer data read from the card and `text()` converts that buffer to ASCII code. `CommClose()` closes the port after completion.

**C# Code**

```cs
[DllImport("F:\\ajm\\Components\\ATM\\New folder (2)\\ATMDev\\ATMCsharp\\inc\\ModuleV188.dll", EntryPoint = "CommOpenWithBaut")]
public static extern Handle CommOpenWithBaut(uint nPort, uint _data);

[DllImport("F:\\ajm\\Components\\ATM\\New folder (2)\\ATMDev\\ATMCsharp\\inc\\ModuleV188.dll", EntryPoint = "CommClose")]
public static extern int CommClose(Handle hComHandle);

[DllImport("F:\\ajm\\Components\\ATM\\New folder (2)\\ATMDev\\ATMCsharp\\inc\\ModuleV188.dll", EntryPoint = "MagRead")]
public static extern int MagRead(Handle hComHandle, Byte[] MagData, int lenth);

[DllImport("F:\\ajm\\Components\\ATM\\New folder (2)\\ATMDev\\ATMCsharp\\inc\\ModuleV188.dll", EntryPoint = "MagRead")]
public static extern int CarderCheckSt(Handle hComHandle,  char PewSt,  char CardType,  char CardSt,  char PowerSt);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Handle port = CommOpenWithBaut(1, 9600);

    Byte[] MagData = {128};

    int lenth = 128;

    MagRead(port, MagData, lenth);

    char PewSt = '0';
    char CardType = '0';
    char CardSt = '0';
    char PowerSt = '0';

    CarderCheckSt(port, PewSt, CardType, CardSt, PowerSt);

    MessageBox.Show($"CarderCheckSt");
    CommClose(port);
}
```

I used `DllImport` to import the same 4 functions from the DLL I used in the previous project. I added a button when clicked, it is suppose to do the same.

**This is the Header file**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#ifdef ModuleV188_EXPORTS
#define ModuleV188_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ModuleV188_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
extern "C" ModuleV188_API HANDLE CommOpenWithBaut(UINT nPort, UINT _data);
extern "C" ModuleV188_API int  CommClose(HANDLE hComHandle);
extern "C" ModuleV188_API int  CarderCheckSt(HANDLE hComHandle, unsigned char& PewSt, unsigned char& CardType, unsigned char& CardSt, unsigned char& PowerSt);
extern "C" ModuleV188_API int  MagRead(HANDLE hComHandle, BYTE* MagData, int& lenth);
```

Also, when the program communicates with the ATM card reader, it writes to a log. The bytes received in the log for both programs.

**for the C++ SUCCESSFUL READ :**

```
18:58:37    COM1´ٍ؟ھ³ة¹¦
18:58:38    ========> 02000231440376
18:58:39    <======== 0200043144303103

18:58:39    <======== 020004314430310371

18:58:39    ========> 0200023B35030D
18:58:39    <======== 0200773B35594234
```

**in the C# log:**

```
10:16:37    COM1´ٍ؟ھ³ة¹¦
```

**FIX**

```
        [DllImport("F:\\ajm\\Components\\ATM\\New folder (2)\\ATMDev\\ATMCsharp\\inc\\ModuleV188.dll", EntryPoint = "CommOpenWithBaut")]
        public static extern IntPtr CommOpenWithBaut(uint nPort, uint _data);

        [DllImport("F:\\ajm\\Components\\ATM\\New folder (2)\\ATMDev\\ATMCsharp\\inc\\ModuleV188.dll", EntryPoint = "CommClose")]
        public static extern int CommClose(IntPtr hComHandle);

        [DllImport("F:\\ajm\\Components\\ATM\\New folder (2)\\ATMDev\\ATMCsharp\\inc\\ModuleV188.dll", EntryPoint = "MagRead")]
        public static extern int MagRead(IntPtr hComHandle, byte[] MagData, ref byte lenth);

        [DllImport("F:\\ajm\\Components\\ATM\\New folder (2)\\ATMDev\\ATMCsharp\\inc\\ModuleV188.dll", EntryPoint = "MagRead")]
        public static extern int CarderCheckSt(IntPtr hComHandle, ref byte PewSt, ref byte CardType, ref byte CardSt, ref byte PowerSt);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            IntPtr port = CommOpenWithBaut(1, 9600);

            Byte[] MagData = {128};

            byte lenth = 128;

            byte PewSt = 0 ;
            byte CardType = 0;
            byte CardSt = 0;
            byte PowerSt = 0;

           // CarderCheckSt(port, ref PewSt, ref CardType, ref CardSt, ref PowerSt);


            MagRead(port, MagData, ref lenth);


            MessageBox.Show($"rc");
            MessageBox.Show($"read");


            CommClose(port);

        }
```

Comment: Your C++ code calls `CarderCheckSt`, then `MagRead` but your C# version calls them in the reverse order.

Comment: Your extern declarations are all wrong. `unsigned char&` should translate to `ref byte` (assuming that the C++ char is compiled as an unsigned 8-bit integer). It's interpreting character values as addresses. Same with the last parameter of `MagRead`.

Comment: @madreflection I believe this is not the issue.The exception is thrown here `Handle port = CommOpenWithBaut(1, 9600);`

Comment: That would've been good information to include from the start. Anyway, I wasn't saying that fixing those problems would fix the error you're reporting, but they still need to be fixed eventually.

Comment: @madreflection yes this is the issue because I don't know the exact declarations in C# from C. Can you please help me with a reference to check those refs for the `MagRead`?

Comment: `HANDLE` is usually returned as `IntPtr`. Since `CommClose` is used to close the handle, you'll need to provide your own `SafeHandle`-derived class that calls it and wrap the returned handle in that. The exception is probably coming from converting `IntPtr` to whatever "`Handle`" is. Beyond that, consult just about any P/Invoke documentation.

Comment: Both IntPtr and handle are 32 bits so the definition should not make a difference.  A char in c# is a class object that is one or two bytes with a private property that determines the number of bytes.  So when communicating with c++ you cannot use a char.  You must change you definition to byte.  You are successfully in c# connecting to the device but just seeing the wrong data int the log file since the definition is wrong.  This is also the reason for the exception.

Comment: That's not how [`System.Char`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Char.cs#L30) is implemented.

Comment: @madreflection  your answer have helped me now its working. I will updated my post with the solution. Thank you.

Comment: @jdweng your answer have helped me now its working. I will updated my post with the solution. Thank you.